# Enhanced loop and possible null value

Tags: java, for-loop, null

If there is a structure, an array for example, which might be `null`, is it valid to use a for/in loop for this structure? For example,

```
String[] a = someFunction(); //some function which might return null  
for (String s : a) {  
 //do something  
}
```

I wonder if this code will crash or not.

Comment: while you wonder, you also could have tried it out yourself by using a simple main method or even better a test, thus -1

Comment: can't you just try it... isn't it a lot easier to try than to post... idk, I might be old-school

Comment: -1. You just asked us to test your code ?

Comment: Think of this a little: What do you want the code do by trying to iterate through `nothing`?

Comment: +1 reasonable question. it will crash, as the answer below says you will get a NullPointerExcetion

Comment: @no_answer_not_upvoted **Exception != Crash**

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ well duh.. thanks for the blindingly obvious insight. the OP is merely trying to determine whether the code will gracefully handle a null or ungracefully. and for that limited purpose npe == crash.

Comment: @no_answer_not_upvoted - Well, nothing wrong with the question. Its a reasonable one to ask, but the OP has done no research/made no efforts to find that out himself and rather has posted it here. If the OP had run the code and then asked, why its not handling, it would have been a better question, properly researched with enough efforts made.

Comment: -1.  Stack Overflow is not a JVM.

Comment: hahaha.. @DavidWallace that quote does make my day :)

Comment: @R.J and DavidWallace .. seriously though, there are plenty of folks willing to answer, .. err to be the JVM, so why mess with the fun? it saves a couple of minutes for the OP to construct an isolated case (i imagine OP is trying to rule out a bug in a larger piece of code where a possibility is that an array might be null) .. i. e. the critique might apply to a question that is languishing for answers.

Comment: If I asked someone this question, and they said "you'll get an NPE", I would never be 100% sure.  I mean, maybe they're wrong.  Maybe it will just not iterate through the loop, like it would if the array were empty.  Even if 4 random strangers all tell me it will give an NPE, I'll still not be quite sure.  But if I write a program that actually does this, and run it, I'll know beyond any doubt at all that this code gives an NPE. So which is better? Spending a few minutes writing the code, running it, and being 100% sure; or spending those minutes posting the same code here and not being sure?

Answer (score 7):

No. You'll get a `NullPointerException`

In such circumstances I always try to return empty collections, rather than null collections. That way I don't have to worry about iterating without a prior `null` check (you could argue this is a *NullObject* pattern)

Answer (score 1):

Make `someFunction()` return an empty array if possible.

Otherwise, yeah. You'll get a `NullPointerException`

Answer (score 1):

> I wonder if this code will crash or not.

Yes. It might crash.

Note that if you return an empty collection, this might ruin your logic. You have to be sure that you don't do unexpected things when you didn't return a non-null value.

I would simply put an `if` that checks if the value returned from `someFunction()` is `null`:

```
if(a != null) {
    for (String s : a) { 
        //...
    }
}
```